# How come I do not get values greater than 2006?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to find the average salary from the years 2006 to 2016 for each team but my code generates this output. Why don't I get values greater than the yearID 2006?

```
payrolls_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT teamID, yearID, salary FROM Salaries WHERE yearID >= 2006 GROUP by teamID;", db)
payrolls_df
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You are not averaging anything. Try:

```
SELECT teamID, yearID, AVG(salary) FROM Salaries WHERE yearID >= 2006 GROUP by teamID, yearId
```